# different kind of hospital bed

Tags: usage

What do you call **"the bed in the hospital  which was considered for that hospital at the time of the approval of the project for building the hospital or its development."**

What kind of bed is it?

Comment: Can you please provide some more context, such as a source of the quotation?

Comment: This looks more like a riddle than something to do with English. (Although a poor riddle, because it's not clear and it's phrased as an awkward run-on sentence.) How can anybody tell what kind of bed it is from that sentence alone? Is there more context?

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I mean the beds that you foresee for a hospital at the time of building one

Comment: Not inpatient beds.

Comment: @Hose why do you think the answer would be different than "hospital bed"?  The planned sinks would be sinks, the planned doors would be doors, the planned light bulbs would be light bulbs.

Comment: @Hose , unless you mean https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/prospective , eventual
expected
proposed
soon-to-be
about to be
approaching
awaited
coming
considered
destined
forthcoming
future
hoped-for
imminent
impending
intended
likely
looked-for
planned
possible
promised
to be
to come